# Data Migration of 200TB of Hadoop data between AWS VPCs

Tags: hadoop, data-migration

I have a technology challenge in my hand. Need to Transfer 200TB of hadoop Data between two different AWS VPCs. There are following restrictions

- No VPC peering
- no third party software installation

Following is the solution throught through. Tried to cut one hop but the performance is not that great

Hadoop Data to EFS data..--> efs to efs --> efs to hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Please dont use efs to efs copy. That's very slow compared to s3 replication.
2) use multiple buckets to replicate data. Go for 10 buckets with replication
3) use distcp to copy data to s3 from hdfs